# preceding setting to use biber

Tags: biber

In Texworks, I add a biber as follows.

In  `Edit` > `preferences` > `Typesetting` tag,

I add biber in Processing tools the `biber` and its path.
Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: In principle that looks OK. But your TeXworks path settings mention `C:/texlive/2013` and you explicitly pick a Biber path in `C:/texlive/2020`. That may result in mismatched `biblatex` and Biber version if LaTeX takes its stuff from the 2013 subtree and Biber is taken from the 2020 subtree. Often it is enough to just write `biber` without the full path in the *Program* bit of the *Tool Configuration* Window. But in any case you may want to adjust the Path settings in the first window to prefer the 2020 version over the 2013 installation.

Comment: Compare also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it and replaced by 2020.